# build config error: file does not exist when building a .war file

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, compiler-errors, war

I'm trying to build a war file for my java project by using gradle task. However,I feep getting this error, but I do have ajc.options in my project, What did I do wrong?

```
Working Directory: C:\Users\weihsiang\Documents\危害鑑別\backend_api
Gradle user home: C:\Users\weihsiang\.gradle
Gradle Distribution: Gradle wrapper from target build
Gradle Version: 7.6
Java Home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202
JVM Arguments: None
Program Arguments: None
Build Scans Enabled: false
Offline Mode Enabled: false
Gradle Tasks: war


> Task :app:compileJava
[error] build config error: file does not exist: C:\Users\weihsiang\Documents\�摰喲�\backend_api\app\build\tmp\compileJava\ajc.options
    
[error] no sources specified
    

2 errors

> Task :app:compileJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileJava'.
> Compilation failed with exit code 2; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
```

Comment: *"... but I do have ajc.options ..."*  - But is it at that precise location?  Gradle doesn't think ... and computers are rarely wrong about things like this.  (If the file is where Gradle is looking for it, then it will find it!)

Comment: The location where Gradle expects to find the file is: "C:\Users\weihsiang\Documents\�摰喲�\backend_api\app\build\tmp\compileJava\ajc.options"

Comment: Also, Gradle told you: `> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.`   Did you try those things?  Did they give you any additional information that might be useful ... to us?